# Create an .exe file from Java project

Tags: java, netbeans-11

So i just finished a small Java program that I've been working on throughout the week and I want to generate an **.exe** file of it so I can share with my friends. I'm working on **Apache Netbeans 11.3** and **JDK 8**.
I can successfully generate the .jar file but that's pretty much useless.

Comment: I've seen tutorials for other versions of netBeans, but those don't work with my version.

Comment: Tried using JSmooth and Launch4j (couldn't wrap my head around either).

Comment: I was required to change the main manifestt, which I did and now I'm being thrown at with the **ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout**. Thing is this class does exist in my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a java project, then the "other" computer should have the java runtime installed, in order for the jar to be executed there (java -jar your.jar) otherwise if you really want an .exe use one of the many jar2exe converters found on the almighty internet, such as  ja2exe you can download it